# outlook for mac can't show attendee

Tags: macos, outlook, calendar, applescript, appointment

On mac we create a Calendar event by script.
The script is

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set newAppointment to make new calendar event with properties {subject: mName, start time: mStartTime, end time: mEndTime, location: mLocation, plain text content: mDescription}
        set theListCount to length of emailList
        if theListCount is greater than 0 then
          delay 2
        end if
        repeat with i from 1 to count emailList
          make new required attendee at newAppointment with properties {email address:{ address: item i in emailList}}
        end repeat
        activate
        open newAppointment
    end tell
```

Run this script, the event is opened with the parameters expect attendee
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz5P4.png)
While restart outlook, the attendee will show normally.

Why attendee no show before, and how to fix it expect restart outlook

I want to know the reason and to fix it